# Java equivalent of a Python functionality -> set(string)

Tags: java, python, set

I want to mimic a Python functionality in Java. 
In Python if I want unique characters in a string I can do just,

```
text = "i am a string"
print set(text) # o/p is set(['a', ' ', 'g', 'i', 'm', 'n', 's', 'r', 't'])
```

How can I do this in Java trivially or directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String str = "i am a string";
System.out.println(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(""))));
```

EDIT: For those who object that they aren't exactly equivalent because str.split will include an empty string in the set, we can do it even more verbose:

```
String str = "i am a string";
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("")));
set.remove("");
System.out.println(set);
```

But of course it depends on what you need to accomplish.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because String.split("") includes an empty string in the result e.g. "hello".split("") is '', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'.

Comment: @mikej well technically the output is '', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'. But I get your point. The current solution works for me though because I further process the result of this operation.

Comment: @Chantz I was giving the output from the split before it goes into the Set to remove duplicates. Thanks.